# Pointer to Integer Array in Class

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c++17

I have a class named `Goal`. This class has an array which stores the goal coordinates `(x,y)`. It also has a function which generates a random goal, sets it and returns a pointer to the goal array.

While creating the pointer `p`, I get an error saying:

> no suitable conversion function from "std::array<int, 2UL>" to "int *" exists

How can I fix this?

I'm also unsure if this pointer will be a shared or unique pointer if I were to use a smart pointer. Though I think it should be unique since `p` will be assigned to some pointer which will call the function.

```
class Goal{
    protected:
    std::array<int,2> goal;
            
    public:
    int* set_goal(){
        srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

        int flag1 = rand() % 2;
        int flag2 = rand() % 2;
        std::unique_ptr<int> p = std::make_unique<int>(Goal::goal);

    
        if(flag1){
            Goal::goal[0] = rand() % 16;
            if(flag2){
                Goal::goal[1] = 0;
                std::cerr << "y - 0";
            }
            else{
                Goal::goal[1] = 15;
                std::cerr << "y - 15";
            }
        }

        else{
            goal[1] = rand() % 16;
            if(flag2){
                Goal::goal[0] = 0;
                std::cerr << "x - 0";
            }
            else{
                Goal::goal[0] = 15;
                std::cerr << "x - 15";
            }
        }

        return p;
    }
};
```

Comment: `std::array` has `data()` method that returns raw pointer to array data. That is, `goal.data()` would give you an `int*`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik how can I implement this using a smart pointer.

Comment: Why are you using pointers?  It looks like you're overcomplicating this.  Why not return a reference to the existing `goal` array member in the class?

Comment: `int* set_goal()` --> `std::array<int, 2>& set_goal() { ... return goal; }` -- No pointers are needed.  It's the usage of `std::unique_ptr<int>` that looks like a bad design, if not overkill.  Allocating memory for a single `int` looks like a design flaw.

Comment: You can safe yourself a bit of typing later : `std::unique_ptr<int> p = std::make_unique<int>(Goal::goal);` can be written as `auto p = std::make_unique<int>(Goal::goal);`. Side note a pointer to just one `int` is a bit of overkill.

Comment: Implement what using a smart pointer? Why do you think you need one here?

Comment: I understand using a pointer especially a smart pointer is overkill but it is a requirement since the assignment is on smart pointers and OOP.

Comment: *but it is a requirement since the assignment is on smart pointers and OOP* -- We have no idea about your assignment -- all we see is the code you're showing us and that is what we are basing the comments on.  It would make a whole lot more sense if instead of a simple `int`, it would be a class or struct of some sort.  You don't really learn a lot by using something (smart pointers in this case) in situations where they are *not* going to be used.  It's like learning how to use a crowbar by using it to take staples out of some pieces of paper.

Comment: I don't think you can return **unique_ptr** because it is **unique**, why would you use that? Use a C-style **int*** pointer. if you want to do this with a unique_ptr you must return a unique_ptr, meaning this **int* set_goal** must be **std::unqiue_ptr<int>** to change. And you also need to put the return value in a unique_ptr! So it is easier to use C-style here.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code fails:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> p = std::make_unique<int>(Goal::goal);
```

Because `std::make_unique<int>()` expects a pointer to the heap, that is, a pointer that was allocated with `new`, that you want `std::unique_ptr<>` to manage.  `Goal::goal` is a member-variable array... NO pointer that would point to the contents of `Goal::goal` is a suitable input parameter for `std::make_unique<int>()`, nor would it be a suitable candidate for ANY type of managed or smart pointer.

Why do you make your life miserable with overly complex code?

You have a single coordinate (x, y) to store.  Why not store that in a proper struct?

As in, for example:

```
// A simple 2d integer point.
struct point_2di
{ 
    int x; 
    int y; 
};

class Goal
{
    protected:
    point_2di goal;
            
    public: 

    // returns a const reference to the goal.
    // this will prevent the caller from changing our (protected) goal
    // behind our back.

    // returning a reference is always preferable to returning a pinter, 
    // it also tells the caller that the return value is always valid.
    // By contrast, a returned pointer could be null, and the 
    // caller should then check if it's valid.  As with anything
    // that needs checking before use, it's a potential source of
    // bugs.  So, its best to avoid returning a pointer as
    // much as possible.

    // since point_2di is small, you could return a copy by value, if you prefer.

    const point_2di& set_goal() 
    {
        srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

        int flag1 = rand() % 2;
        int flag2 = rand() % 2;
    
        if (flag1) {
            goal.x = rand() % 16;  // using named members make your code 
            if(flag2){             // easier to read and avoids silly bugs.
                goal.y = 0;
                std::cerr << "y <- 0";
            }
        }
              
        // etc...
        return goal;
    }
};
```